# Csv files are not get generating in var folder

Tags: magento2, csv, magento2.3.3

I want to generate a csv file in var folder.  I used these lines of code it's not working.  Can someone help me to figure it out

```
public function execute()
{
    $filepath = 'export/customerlist.csv';
    $this->directory->create('export');
    $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
    $stream->lock();

    $header = ['Id', 'Name', 'Email'];
    $stream->writeCsv($header);

    $collection = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $customer) {
        $data = [];
        $data[] = $customer->getId();
        $data[] = $customer->getName();
        $data[] = $customer->getEmail();
        $stream->writeCsv($data);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: give your path here $filepath = 'export/customerlist.csv';

Answer (score 2):

just you need set var directory like this `\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR`
try below code

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class SampleCsv extends Action
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $name = date('m-d-Y-H-i-s');
        $filepath = 'export/sample-data-' . $name . '.csv'; // at Directory path Create a Folder Export and FIle
        $this->directory->create('export');

        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();

        //column header name display in your CSV
        $columns = ['identifier', 'sku', 'special_price', 'deal_quantity', 'sort_order'];
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $header[] = $column; //column in Header array
        }
        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        $sampleData[] = array('aug2020', 'sku1', '100.00', '25', '1');
        $sampleData[] = array('sep2020', 'sku2', '2000.00', '32', '2');

        foreach ($sampleData as $data) {
            $itemData = []; //sample row data array
            $itemData[] = $data[0];
            $itemData[] = $data[1];
            $itemData[] = $data[2];
            $itemData[] = $data[3];
            $itemData[] = $data[4];
            $stream->writeCsv($itemData);
        }

        $content = [];
        $content['type'] = 'filename'; // must keep filename
        $content['value'] = $filepath;
        $content['rm'] = '1'; //remove csv from var folder
        $csvfilename = 'deals-offers-sample-' . $name . '.csv';

        return $this->_fileFactory->create($csvfilename, $content, \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to generate the same csv inside a code/vendorname/modulename/csv.  I have tried this but its not working.

 $directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite($directory::APP);
 $filepath = 'code/Vendorname/Modulename/File/Sample/refund.csv';

Comment: no, it's not possible. better create a folder in var directory whatever your module name same name. and save all CSV in that folder itself